# Explicit initialization of primitives

Tags: java, initialization

I understand that Java primitives have default initialization values; for example `0` for `int`.

From my research it seems that I should not rely on these values. Should I always provide an explicit initialization and if so, where?

Here's part of my program:

```
public class Calculator {

// Initialize value where it's declared?
private int value;

public Calculator() {
    // Initialize value in constructor?
}

public void add(int other) {
    value += other;
}
}
```

Comment: "From my research it seems that I should not rely on these values" <-- uh? The language specification is not enough of a reliable source for you?

Comment: It's less about relying on the values and more about making it explicit to other programmers what value you are using.

Comment: If you don;t need the default value and logically every instance of your class should have instance variables set to at least a particular value , then you can use constructor for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using default values produced by Java is absolutely OK, you do not need to explicitly initialize instance or `static` fields of your `class`. Java Language Specification requires this, so any implementation of the language must comply. In other words, your code would remain 100% portable if you use default values of member variables. This applies to both primitive and reference types (the later are initialized with `null`).

See [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), page 81, for more details.

> 4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables
>
> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>   - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a
>   default value when it is created

The only case where you must provide explicit initialization is when you declare local variables:

> A local variable must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization or assignment, in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment.

However, since failure to initialize a local is a compile-time error, the compiler will pinpoint every missing initialization before you can run your program.

Answer (score 1):

> From my research it seems that I should not rely on these values.

You can rely on them. There will be no harm, as it is done by default as you already know.

> Should I always provide an explicit initialization and if so, where?

For primitives, no it's not necessary to provide the explicit initialization, and I prefer not to. I rarely do and see people to do an initialization like - `int i = 0;` for instance variables. But, if you are talking about local variables, then you need to give them explicit values. The defaults are not implicit there.

But when the case comes for non-primitives, then you should do an explicit initialization, either at the point of declaration, or inside the constructor, as the values are by default `null`, which might result in `NPE`, if not taken care of. The benefit of initializing at the point of declaration is that, you won't have to put the initialization in each of your constructors.

Comment: You should avoid initializing local variables with default or "dummy" variables. This inhibits the static analysis performed by the compiler that could alert you to a code path you overlooked. For example, if you declare a local variable, and later read it without ever having assigned a value it, the compiler will alert you. If you had initialized it with a meaningless default, the compiler won't detect your bug. So, leave declarations blank, or wait to declare a variable until you can initialize it with a real value.

Comment: @erickson. Yeah right. Actually I meant that only. It's good practice to declare the local variables as and when you need it. this saves a lot of work, when you get stuck in some odd problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize variables in the constructor if you're really worried about this.  However, I've never seen a numeric primitive initialized to anything other than zero.

I'd think you'd only need to worry about this if you were working with some custom (and poor) JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The member variables will be initialized with default values. So you need not worry about that. But still if you want to initialize with default values or other values you can set them in constructor

Comment: without constructor: public class A {
    public int num = 2;
    public void A() {       
    }    
}

Comment: initialize in constructor is better one .

Comment: it may be. I just offer other method

Comment: that's good , i thought my answer got the downvote for suggesting to initialize in constructor :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the code you write should always do the least surprising thing possible. If you feel that a default of zero for a variable that isn't explicitly initialized is surprising then perhaps you should make sure that you always assign an initial value even if it's zero.

My personal preference in the code you've shown would be to initialize the variable to 0 when declared. This is simply because the first operation on the variable is `+=` and to me it feels wrong to rely on the default value for numerical operations. There's no good reason for this as it will work fine as it is it just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly trust JVM primitive initialization with default values.

---

BTW, explicit initialization will be translated into bytecode which is useless in this case.

Say you have this class :

```
public class PrimitiveInitialization {
    int i = 0;
    int j;
}
```

Corresponding bytecode will be

```
class PrimitiveInitialization {
  I i
  I j

  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 10 L1
    ALOAD 0
    ICONST_0
    PUTFIELD PrimitiveInitialization.i : I
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this LPrimitiveInitialization; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

We can see that explicit initialization adds few bytecode operations for variable `i`.

That said, *you must always prefer code readability*, as JIT is probably able to optimize this kind of bytecode at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The default values are dependable.

---

Actually they are "more" dependable than explicit zeroing, because the default assignments happens-before all other actions.